# Formatting Orbeon Date input fields

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to format an input field of the type xs:date in Orbeon.
I have tried using the xxf:format attribute, but the datepicker can not understand the date when it has been modified.

The idea now was to change the javascript of Orbeon to use the xxf:unformat attribute to interpret the date and transform it back to ISO format.
I've tried changing the data.js but for some reason none of the changes can be seen.

Am I changing the wrong file?

**Edit**

I figured out that the xforms.js has a function 'getCurrentValue' which is being as the changes I do there are visible. Now I just need to figure out who is the one that's calling the function.

**Edit:**

It is the Calendar who requests the value of the input when the user clicks on the symbol. This all happens at the client side, and the generated HTML does not have the format/unformat attributes. However I want to use their value. Can I make a request to Orbeon to get it? How?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using an `xf:input` bound to a node of type `xs:date`, you can [control the formatting of the date field](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/xforms.html#for-xfinput) with the `oxf.xforms.format.input.date` property. A few formats are supported, and if you want to add more, the best would be to follow the pattern currently used for the currently supported formats.

E.g.

```
[M]/[D]/[Y]
[Y]-[M01]-[D01]
```

Comment: I've read about that option too. But I'm not sure it suits my needs. We need to be able to have a very flexible formatting. We actually generate the XForm from some input. We must also be able to have different formattings for different inputs.

Comment: @cvesters If it doesn't suit your needs in the sense that it doesn't support the formats you want, maybe you can extend it. (And if what you do can be useful to others, you can maybe even contribute your changes to the product.) The server and the client always exchange dates in the ISO format (e.g. `2015-06-28`), so to support a new format, you'll want to add both code on the client and server-side.

Comment: I think that's a bit where the problem lies. I don't know the exact dataflow. Which files would I have to change? I have done something similar for numbers by just using xxf:format and xxf:unformat. But for date this isn't possible as the date picker doesn't recognize the format.

Comment: @cvesters Exactly, dates are different, since for dates we also need to be able to do the formatting/unformatting on the client, not just on the server. I would start by making the changes to the client-side code. You can see what code is called in `Calendar.coffee`. Search for `DateTime.` to find the name of the function that get called (e.g. `DateTime.magicDateToJSDate`, `DateTime.jsDateToISODate`). Then those are implemented in `xforms.js`, which is the file you'll want to change first.

Comment: @cvesters If you're using a format that is recognized by `format-date()`, which I would highly recommend, then you might not need to change any server side code, as the server just calls format-date() with the format specified in the property (see `formatSubValue()` in `XFormsInputControl.scala`).

Comment: The format-date() function is really strong. It allows a lot of flexibility, and I'm sure it will satisfy our needs. The problem is that if we change the date from a '[D]/'[M]/[Y]' notation to something as '[D]th of [M], [Y]'. The datepicker can not show the correct date, as it doesn't understand the formatted date.
Maybe the biggest problem is that we don't know what our customers will come up with. They are free to specify any formatting they like. This makes it impossible to implement all formatting as a magic date.

Comment: For reference, the [forum discussion on this](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Format-input-date-type-td4660150.html).